# Exclude items from sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

I have below sample table code,

```
<table id="Table1">
<thead>
    <th>Title</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='disabled'>
        <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm applying below jQuery Sortable, which works fine,

```
$("#Table1 tbody").sortable({
});
```

But, now I want to exclude sortable for "tr" having class "disabled", to do I'm applying below code (the jquery selector), but it DOESN't work. Is there anything wrong with selector? I have to use "thead" and "tbody" in HTML table.

Or is there any alternative approach? Thanks,

```
$("#Table1 tbody tr:not(.disabled)").sortable({
});
```

Comment: you've miss the table header so we can't verify the id

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`items`](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) option:

> *Specify which items are eligible to sort by passing a jQuery selector
>   into the items option. Items excluded from this option are not
>   sortable, nor are they valid targets for sortable items.*

```
$("#Table1 tbody").sortable({
    items: 'tr:not(.disabled)'  
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hJVYG/5/)

Answer (score 1):

you can Use `items` option to specifiy which items inside the element should be sortable.  Like:

```
$("#Table1 tbody").sortable({
    items: ':not(.disabled)'
});
```

[Click here](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) for more references: